# Reading from CosmosDB and write to Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, database, function, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have an Azure function to read from Cosmos DB and write to SQL. Since I am new to coding I have a little of struggle to understand how to read the incoming document. I can see that documents are shown at **input**:

```
        public static async Task Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "ToDoList",
            collectionName: "Items",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDB",
            LeaseCollectionName = "leases")]IReadOnlyList<Document> input, ILogger log)
        {
            if (input != null && input.Count > 0)
            { }
```

I know that I have to read the document and deserialise it to a C# object which I have this code for (assuming it is correct):

```
Record resultRecord = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Record>(jsonString);
```

I am lost how to get the data from the json document and write it to the C# object. The connecting part is confusing for me.

I also have a SQL code, and again I dont understand how I should connect my C# object so the data can be read and written to SQL database.

```
                var cnnString = "sqlConnection";    // Connecting to Azure SQL Database

                using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(cnnString))    // Start up sql connectin with connectionstring
                {
                    sqlConnection.Open();
                    var cmd = new SqlCommand
                    {
                        //Insert into command (used to insert data into a table)
                        CommandText = @"insert into [dbo].[Player] ([User] values(@User)",
                        CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                        Connection = sqlConnection,
                    };

                    var record = new Record();
                    //set parameters
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@User", record.Email));

                    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
```

I am not sure if this is the right way of asking a question about a code, but I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to get data from a json document,we can use the Newtonsoft.Json.dll file to parse the json document.
I think you can change you code like this:

```
List<Info> jobInfoList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Info>>(json);
```

And here is a sample about how to get data from a json documnet:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = @"[{'id':9527,'username':'admin'}]";
            List<Info> jobInfoList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Info>>(json);

            foreach (Info jobInfo in jobInfoList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("UserName:" + jobInfo.username);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Info
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }         
    }
```

You can declare variables to receive the data which you want to get from the json String in `foreach` . Then you can insert these data into your sql database as the parameters.

How to connect to the sql database and write data to sql database,you can see:

Quickstart: 
Use .NET (C#) with Visual Studio to connect and query an Azure SQL database
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-dotnet-visual-studio#insert-code-to-query-sql-database